# How to preload or initialize a search using UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I added a UISearchDisplayController to my UITableViewController in InterfaceBuilder. It was very easy to get it working by adding a `searchBar: searchBar textDidChange: searchText` method that regenerates the data array for the table and calls `reloadData`.

But I would like to have the previous search show the next time the users touches in the search bar since it is much easier to touch the (X) and clear it than type it in again. But I cannot get it to do it. Below is the code I've tried:

```
- (void) searchBar: (UISearchBar *) searchBar textDidChange: (NSString *) searchText {
    if( searchText && [searchText length] > 0 ) {
        self.displayedRows = [[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity: 1];
        for( NSString *l in self.allRows ) {
            NSRange r = [l rangeOfString: searchText];
            if( r.location != NSNotFound )
                [self.displayedRows addObject: l];
        }
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller {
    if( self.lastSearch && [self.lastSearch length] > 0 ) {
        controller.searchBar.text = self.lastSearch;
        [controller.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller {
    self.lastSearch = controller.searchBar.text;
    self.displayedRows = self.allRows;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The last search text is appropriately in the search bar the next time I touch the search and I was surprised that the 'cursor' is even positioned at the end but the search results are not shown, just the darkened view of the original contents like the search field was empty. As soon as I type a character the search results are updated.

I've tried putting the equivalent of `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]` into each of:

```
searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller
searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller willShowSearchResultsTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller didShowSearchResultsTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
```

But it made no difference... just blank until I type something.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get a preloaded search result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if(lastSearch.length > 0) {
        NSLog(@"In searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch");
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:lastSearch];
    }
}
```

If you need to make further changes, I suggest opening up the `UIKit` headers `UISearchBar.h` and `UISearchDisplayController.h` and looking at what you can overload and where. Also, `NSLog` is your friend =)

**Also**

Just to explain what is going on and how this is different from `...searchBar.text = lastSearch`, `setText` forces `textDidChange` to register, which in turn redoes the search, and subsequently has a call to `shouldReloadTableForSearchString`. Just changing the text without using `setText` (for some reason) doesn't trigger `textDidChange`.

Comment: Amazing, I thought I had tried every possible combination of all the different willBegins and didBegins but I was only moving the `reloadData` part since the previous search test was always in the search field.

Comment: I tried, like you suggested moving the `controller.searchBar.text = self.lastSearch` and presto, it works (which a little dark-flash that it would be nice to not have). I don't even seem to need the `reloadData`.  Thanks.

Comment: (Oh, and I had so many `NSLogs`. I had them when I was entering and leaving methods and showing field contents and array sizes... it just wouldn't update).

Comment: @LavaSlider: It took me a few hours of adding all the methods from the `.h` files and then determining the order of function calls and the dependencies. And I also encountered your exact problem so I'm glad this saved you some trouble as well.

Comment: The difference that makes the difference here is to call it in didBegin instead of willBegin.

Comment: No, it is the setText vs searchBar.text. Yes, it matters _where_ it is executed. But _what_ is executed was the point of concern here.